# Gradle not using latest version of the support library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library, android-recyclerview

I've been using the `android.support.v7.widget` package -- specifically the `RecyclerView` class (among others but this is where the problem is).

It was working fine until earlier today it randomly seems to default to an earlier version of the package now. I say that because:

1. When I try calling `myRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(myScrollListener)`, `myRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(myView)` etc Android Studio gives the compile error `Cannot resolve method ...`.
2. If I change it to `myRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(myScrollListener)` (ie use `set` instead of `add`), it works fine and does not show the deprecated error, which it should because the method is deprecated.

I don't know why it's showing errors now when I've been using and have been able to compile with these methods earlier -- it seems as though it's using an earlier version of `android.support.v7.widget` library but I have no idea why it would or how to fix it...

**edit:** my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.1'

compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

compile 'com.joooonho:selectableroundedimageview:1.0.1'

compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.3'

}
```

Comment: It isn't really Android Studio that determines that. It is your gradle build files that determine your library versions. What do you have in your gradle files for the support libraries.

Comment: new android v7 support is `22.2.0` and you can change it from `dependencies`

Comment: I have a few custom dependencies, the `v7:21.0.3` appcompat library, and the `v4:21.0.3` support library. (I can add a screenshot if you want)

Comment: post your gradle build files

Comment: added my build.gradle

Comment: I don't see if you have added RecyclerView dependency to your gradle script. Also, keep in mind, it doesn't come with `appcompat` package.

Comment: Isn't the `RecyclerView` just a part of the support library? I'm able to import it fine by referring to it with `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` and I dont think I've removed any dependencies since it was working.

Comment: I am not sure, How are you able to import it, But if you want to use RecyclerView, you need to add its dependency, i.e. `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'`

Comment: remove compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie True! As all v4 package comes with appcompat support package, you don't need to add it explicitly.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, I added that dependency and it worked! I looked at one of my previous commits on git, and it seems that earlier I had also added the dependency `'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.1.0'` and it works if I add that back, but I'm curious as to *why*... since I was still importing `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` and I'm not sure what the relationship would be between those two libraries?

Comment: In other words, why would that dependency make it so that I'm using the most up-to-date version of the `v7.widget.RecyclerView`?

Comment: By adding that dependency `'com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards:cardslib-recyclerview:2.1.0'`, you're actually adding recyclerview dependency. Have a look : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/library-recyclerview/build.gradle

Comment: Oh okay I see, that makes a lot of sense! If you add an answer maybe to that effect I can accept it to close this question.

Comment: `cardslib-recyclerview 2.1.0` uses the 
    `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, How are you able to import it, But if you want to use RecyclerView, you need to add its dependency, i.e. compile `'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'`

I don't see if you have added `RecyclerView` dependency to your gradle script. Also, keep in mind, it doesn't come with appcompat package.

Comment: It is possible, if a dependency uses the RecyclerView.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Well it is possible. But the list of dependencies, he has in his script which he posted in his question , I don't see any dependency has RecyclerView. So...

Comment: @rekire Thanks, Edited with the latest version!  ;-)